# Compare Table To Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (`claim 24`) that has a column (`status`) with a number 2 for every invalid claim and a (`filled`) column which is the date range of April-August for invalid claims.

I have nine other tables (`claim 25`-`claim 33`) where the (`status`) column equals zero and the (`filled`) column is April-August.

All ten tables have the same columns (`fname`, `lname`, `DOB`, `status`, `filled`).

I'm trying to find the invalid claims in previous (`claim 24`) table that aren't invalid anymore

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for records in `claim24` that have `status` **2** but in one of other claim tables the `status` is **0**?

Comment: Is the combination of `fname`, `lname`, and `DOB` **unique** for all tables?

Comment: can we assume you have some unique identifier that can be used to join these tables?

Comment: If you show the SQL you would use if you just had two table [claim24 and claim25], that would make your requirement clear. Then, someone can help you extend that to mutliple tables.